# AJax for Remove from Cart is not doing anything

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to have this AJAX code working.  When I run the WebStore it display a list of categories which If I clicked on 1 category, I can then select a product.  The product show up and I can added to the cart.  After it's been added to the cart, I clicked on Remove from the Cart and nothing is refreshing.  I based my solution on the MVC Music Store and I also read the old solution was not updated for this Ajax Part.  I found this instead and I guess I am missing something.
I noticed an URL change localhost:49523/Panier#.    Any idea why a # is there ?

Thanks

index.cshtml from panier

```
 @model Tp1WebStore3.ViewModels.ShoppingCartViewModel

 @{
     ViewBag.Title = "Shopping Cart";
 }
 <script src="/Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="/Scripts/MicrosoftMvcAjax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript">
     function handleUpdate(context) {
         // Load and deserialize the returned JSON data
         var json = context.get_data();
         var data = Sys.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.deserialize(json);

         // Update the page elements
         $('#row-' + data.DeleteId).fadeOut('slow');
         $('#cart-status').text('Cart (' + data.CartCount + ')');
         $('#update-message').text(data.Message);
         $('#cart-total').text(data.CartTotal);
     }
 </script>
 <h3>
     <em>Details</em> du panier:
 </h3>
 <p class="button">
     @Html.ActionLink("Checkout >>", "AddressAndPayment", "Checkout")
 </p>
 <div id="update-message">
 </div>
 <table>
   <tr>
     <th>
        Produit
     </th>
     <th>
        Prix (unitaire)
     </th>
     <th>
        Quantite
     </th>
     <th></th>
   </tr>
   @foreach (var item in Model.CartItems)
   {
       <tr id="row-@item.ProduitId">
         <td>
            @Html.ActionLink(item.Produit.Description,"Details", "Panier", new { id = 
                 item.ProduitId }, null)
         </td>
         <td>
            @item.Produit.Prix
         </td>
         <td id="item-count-@item.ProduitId">
               @item.Quantite
         </td>
         <td>

            <a href="#" class="RemoveLink" data-id="@item.ProduitId"> Remove from Cart </a>
         </td>
       </tr>
   }
   <tr>
      <td>
         Total
      </td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td id="cart-total">
          @Model.CartTotal
      </td>
   </tr>
 </table>
```

PanierController.cs

```
    // AJAX: /ShoppingCart/RemoveFromCart/5
    [HttpPost] 
    public ActionResult RemoveFromCart(int id)
    {
        // Remove the item from the cart
        var cart = ShoppingCart.GetCart(this.HttpContext);

        // Get the name of the album to display confirmation
        string produitDescription = dbProduit.Paniers
            .Single(item => item.PanierId == id).Produit.Description;

        // Remove from cart
        int itemCount = cart.RemoveFromCart(id);

        // Display the confirmation message
        var results = new ShoppingCartRemoveViewModel
        {
            Message = Server.HtmlEncode(produitDescription) +
                " has been removed from your shopping cart.",
            CartTotal = cart.GetTotal(),
            CartCount = cart.GetCount(),
            ItemCount = itemCount,
            DeleteId = id
        };
        return Json(results);
```

Modify Index.cshtml

```
 @model Tp1WebStore3.ViewModels.ShoppingCartViewModel

 @{
     ViewBag.Title = "Shopping Cart";
 }
 <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('.RemoveLink').click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                 url: '/Panier/RemoveFromCart',
                 data: { id: $(this).data('id') },
                 cache: false,
                 success: function (result) {
                      $('#row-' + result.DeleteId).fadeOut('slow');
                      $('#cart-status').text('Cart (' + result.CartCount + ')');
                      $('#update-message').text(result.Message);
                      $('#cart-total').text(result.CartTotal);
                 }
             });
             return false;
         });
     });
 </script>
```

I am adding also the 
ShoppingCart.cs

```
    public int RemoveFromCart(int id)
    {
        // Get the cart
        var cartItem = db.Paniers.Single(
            cart => cart.CartId == ShoppingCartId
            && cart.ProduitId == id);

        int itemCount = 0;

        if (cartItem != null)
        {
            if (cartItem.Quantite > 1)
            {
                cartItem.Quantite--;
                itemCount = cartItem.Quantite;
            }
            else
            {
                db.Paniers.Remove(cartItem);
            }
            // Save changes
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        return itemCount;
```

I got more information.  When I ran Chrome with PF12 and Network, I saw a page not found

In my Panier I got this key (newly created) for the CartId : dbfac4de-ae5e-4fbf-a44a-f6bb8ee3f2fc

In Chrome it complaining about this:
RemoveFromCart?id=dbfac4de-ae5e-4fbf-a44a-f6bb8ee3f2fc&_=1394045298037
/Panier

I don't understand the next part of the key (concatenation)  &_=1394045298037
My ProduitId are define like this for the key: 3

Can anyone explain this to me ?

Answer (score 1):

You have a remove anchor:

```
<a href="#" class="RemoveLink" data-id="@item.ProduitId">Remove from Cart </a>
```

and some javascript `handleUpdate` function which is absolutely never called:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function handleUpdate(context) {
        // Load and deserialize the returned JSON data
        var json = context.get_data();
        var data = Sys.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.deserialize(json);

         // Update the page elements
         $('#row-' + data.DeleteId).fadeOut('slow');
         $('#cart-status').text('Cart (' + data.CartCount + ')');
         $('#update-message').text(data.Message);
         $('#cart-total').text(data.CartTotal);
    }
</script>
```

You also seem to be using an extremely outdated version of jquery:

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and a dinosaurly old, stone age outdated and deprecated Microsoft AJAX scripts:

```
<script src="/Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/MicrosoftMvcAjax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

So start by removing the dinosaurly old scripts from your ASP.NET MVC application as well as the `handleUpdate` function which is absolutely never used.

Then you could write some jQuery ajax function that will subscribe to the click event of your anchor and perform an AJAX request:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('.RemoveLink').click(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/ShoppingCart/RemoveFromCart',
                data: { id: $(this).data('id') },
                cache: false,
                success: function(result) {   
                    $('#row-' + result.DeleteId).fadeOut('slow');
                    $('#cart-status').text('Cart (' + result.CartCount + ')');
                    $('#update-message').text(result.Message);
                    $('#cart-total').text(result.CartTotal);
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Also you should learn how to debug your AJAX calls in your web browser. All modern web browsers (such as Google Chrome) come with javascript debugging tools that would help you debug and analyze such problems. So don't hesitate to fire your debugging toolbar using <kbd>F12</kbd> and look at the `Network` tab. It will provide you useful information about all network requests (including AJAX) that the browser is making. The `Console` tab will show you any potential javascript errors you might be having in your code. So instead of saying on StackOverflow that nothing happens when you click on some anchor, next time use your javascript debugging toolbar to analyze what happens under the covers.

Comment: I am following the ASP.net MVC Music Store. It should have been updated by someone at Microsoft....  anyway I have perform the asking changes on nothing happen when I click on Remove from Cart.  Also I went to my scripts folder and I saw the version for the Jquery was 1.8.2.

Comment: I added the modified Index.cshtml.  No easy for a beginner to follow ASP.net example when it is outdated !  Thanks for your help

Comment: I am not able to figure out why it is still not working ?  Can you give me any more hint ?  Thanks

Comment: The javascript is still not reacting.  Nothing is happening.  I used IE I and PF12 but a break point but when I run I got this message Unable to attach to process. Another debugger might be attached to the process